# how to convert values in columns to a vector using R

Tags: r, plot

I have a file like this. I am just using a single row as of now for simplicity.

```
AA  12  gene1   1004265 197007  19.6    18 320 315 1913 2907 1495 280 130 475 34 1437 1000
```

The file is tab delimited and the 7th column (last column) has values separated by spaces (18 320 315 etc)

If you see number of values in column 7, it is equal to column 2 which is 12 here.

```
vec <- 1:12
```

I want to make a vector of the 7th column values lets say some thing like this

```
count <- c(18,320,315,1913,2907,1495,280,130,475,34,1437,1000)
```

and then plot

```
plot(vec,count,type="b")
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I see in 2nd column 12... However, this will extract all values from 7th column to the last one.

       framesize <- ncol(DataFrame)
       extractedVector <- DataFrame[,7:framesize]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first read your table into R:

```
tab <- read.table("table.txt", sep="\t", header=F)
```

Then you can use `strsplit` to split up column 7, which can then be plotted:

```
plot(as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(tab[1,7]), " ")[[1]]), type="b")
```

[image]

Comment: What does stringAsFactors do??
When i use class command on my 7th column it gives me result as factors

Comment: @user3138373 it ensures your strings are read in as strings instead of as factors. I've updated the code to your situation (where you have a factor in the seventh column). The only change is that you pass `as.character(tab[1,7])` instead of `tab[1,7]` to `strsplit`.

Comment: Thanks, but the previous code also worked because stringAsFactors was F so moment this option was used in reading the file, the class command on column 7 returned character which can now be used for strsplit

Comment: Hi josilber: Can you explain me the use of [[1]], in the code

Comment: `strsplit` returns a list, and `[[1]]` grabs the first element of the list. You can read [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list) for more details.